# Create RequestMock with dynamic url (params) Testcafe

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I'm trying to test login page of my react app using testcafe. After success login app should fetch user from API (on localhost:5000) and display name & surname on the home page.

Fetching user in my app:

```js
const raw = await axios.get(`http://localhost:5000/api/user/${uid}`);
```

tests/login.test.ts

```js
// Used to mock POST /login-user
const loginMock = RequestMock()
    .onRequestTo("http://localhost:5000/api/login-user")
    .respond(
        {
            success: true,
            id: "123456789101",
        },
        200,
        { "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*" }
    );

// Used to mock GET /user/:id
const getUserMock = RequestMock()
    .onRequestTo("http://localhost:5000/api/user/:id")
    .respond(
        {
            success: true,
            user: {
                name: "John",
                surname: "McBain",
            },
        },
        200,
        { "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*" }
    );

test.requestHooks([loginMock, getUserMock])("should login user", async t => {
    /* login user testing*/
    ...

    // Check GET /user
    const UserInfo = await Selector(".auth span");
    await browser
        .expect(await UserInfo.textContent)
        .eql("Account: John McBain"); // Failed here "Account undefined undefined" != "Account John McBain"
});
```

POST /login-user request is working fine, but GET /user/:id request is failed
I think the problem is that I'm incorrectly write dynamic url (/:id/). How can I do it correctly?
My express server function for GET /user/:id here:

```js
app.get("/api/user/:id", (req, res) => {
    const userId = req.params.id;
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case of dynamic URLs you should use `RegExp` instead of `string` in your [`RequestMock.onRequestTo` method](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/reference/test-api/requestmock/onrequestto.html). The result `RegExp` relates to your `id` possible symbols, [for example](https://regex101.com/r/zj9zyf/1):

```js
const mock = RequestMock()
    .onRequestTo(/\/id=[0-9]+$/)
    .respond(/*...*/);
```

Result:

```
[respond is replaced by mock]     https://example.com/id=13234
[respond is not replaced by mock] https://example.com/id=23443-wrong-part
[respond is not replaced by mock] https://example.com/id=wrong-non-number-id
```